# Explain 2D ellipse function in terms of Circ

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis, circles

Suppose we have a two dimensional continuous linear shift invariant system has impulse response:
$h(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{1}{2\pi a^2 b^2},  & \mbox{if } (\frac{x}{a_2})^2+(\frac{y}{b_2})^2 \leq 1 \\
  0 & elsewhere
 \end{array}
\right.$

now I want to express the mentioned ellipse function in terms of circ function:

$circ(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  1,  & \mbox{if } (x^2)+(y^2) \leq 1 \\
  0 & elsewhere
 \end{array}
\right.$

Your attention would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$h(x,y)=\frac1{2\pi a^2b^2}\cdot circ(\frac x{a_2},\frac y{b_2})$$

Answer (score 1):

$$h(x,y)=\frac1{2\pi a^2b^2}\operatorname{circ}\left(\frac x{a_2},\frac y{b_2}\right)$$